# Linux kernel and my kernel module

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I was trying to put in my driver as part of the Linux kernel. The following is the Makefile. The module, rs_pci depends on rs_9x. However, the kernel tries to build rs_pci before building rs_9x, which causes the compilation of rs_pci to fail. I would like the kernel to compile rs_9x first and then compile rs_pci. How do I do it?

The following is my Makefile

```
rs_9x-y                       += rs_a.o
rs_9x-y                       += rs_b.o
rs_9x-y                       += rs_c.o

rs_pci-y                      += rs_pci.o rs_pci_ops.o
obj-$(CONFIG_RS)               := rs_9x.o
obj-$(CONFIG_RS_PCI)           := rs_pci.o

In the .config file, I have both options enabled as modules.
CONFIG_RS=m
CONFIG_RS_PCI=m
```

Please help me out.

Comment: It might be easier to help you out if you post the build output

Comment: Why does the compilation order matter? This would indicate a bug in the `rs_pci` module.

Answer (score 0):

First check : Make sure CONFIG_RS is enabled

Second check : put rs_9x.o above of rs_pci.o like below :

```
obj-$(CONFIG_RS)    += rs_9x.o
rs_pci-y    += rs_pci.o rs_pci_ops.o
obj-$(CONFIG_RS_PCI)    += rs_pci.o
```

also try changing ":" to "+" as I did above, it will work out for you.